# Formula for calculating remaining days

Tags: administration, formula

I have two fields in an object, `Total_Casual_Leaves__c (Formula)` 15 is constant value for it. `Days_Requested__c  (Number)` that is user input. Now i want to write a formula for `Remaining_leaves__c` after  `Days_Requested__c` taken. for that i am trying to write something like this

```
IF(
 OR(
    ISPICKVAL( Type_of_Leave__c , "Casual Leave"),
    ISPICKVAL(Type_of_Leave__c, "Sick Leave")
   ),
   Total_Casual_Leaves__c -  Days_Requested__c ,
   Total_Sick_Leaves__c  -  Days_Requested__c 
  )
```

Its working fine for one instance but if i create a new record then its taking 15 records as total leaves . If i enter a new record then it must calculate using `Remaining_leaves__c`. Could any one help me out

Comment: Is your `Total_Casual_Leaves__c` field in formula type?

Comment: @highfive yes its formula type with a constant value 15 in it

Answer (score 1):

Formula are limited for that specific record. In formula you can not refer other records from same object. If you want o do that then you will need to use trigger and write your won logic.

Comment: If Salesforce developer's fields are in the detail object of a master-detail relationship, they might be able to solve their problem using roll-up summary fields and a formula field on the master object.